# Can't load Kernel binary: Invalid SDK hash in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

Whenever I try to run a dart tool like Dart Migrate I get the following error and I am unable to run that tool. Is there a way to solve this problem or I have to reinstall Flutter?
[image]

Btw every thing is okay with Flutter Doctor

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After a lot of effort and wasting a lot of time on this issue I have been able to solve this problem. I have installed dart-sdk separately in the past and place the path of that dart-sdk at the top (before flutter one) in environment variables PATH. So I deleted that old dart-sdk path and deleted the respective folder this solved my problem.

Answer (score 4):

`dart pub global activate rps (or some other package)`

After each update it invalids these packages.

Comment: Actually this was the solution in my case where I upgraded Flutter and running Melos was yielding this error. Thanks. ;)

Answer (score 1):

## In VS Code, if you get "Can't Load Kernel binary: Invalid SDK Hash" in Flutter or Dart, update `dart.sdkPath` setting

If you get this in VS Code, in addition to re-downloading the dart-sdk, make sure the "dart.sdkPath" setting in user/workspace settings is pointing to the new SDK. In my case, even though I had it in my path as in [Junaid's](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67074432/2205849) answer, VS Code was still looking to the old dart-sdk folder and giving me the kernel hash error. I updated the dart.sdkPath to the correct path and restarted VS Code:

For example, in Windows:

1. Download [dart sdk](https://dart.dev/get-dart)
2. Unzip it to c:\tools\dart-sdk or any other folder (make sure you rename or delete the existing dart-sdk folder)
3. `ctrl-shift-p`, type 'user settings (JSON)', open the json settings, and add:

```
  "dart.sdkPath": "C:\\tools\\dart-sdk",
```

4. Update your system PATH environmental variable to point to the new dart-sdk and delete the reference to the old location.
5. Restart VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

Note that Instead of This "dart.sdkPath": "D:\Dart\dart-sdk\bin" work well for me.
path should be included '\bin' also. It work for me

Answer (score 0):

For me, trying to run pana and seeing this error, was just a metter or reinstalling it:

```dart
dart pub global activate pana
```