# Can't run flutter project due to error VERBOSE.dart error, isolate error

Tags: flutter, dart, runtime, verbose

When I try to run my flutter-project code on the iOS simulator in VS code, I get the following error on the console:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 Pro in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1
Xcode build done.                                           24.4s
[VERBOSE-2:shell.cc(103)] Dart Error: Can't load Kernel binary: Invalid SDK hash.
[VERBOSE-2:dart_isolate.cc(171)] Could not prepare isolate.
[VERBOSE-2:runtime_controller.cc(415)] Could not create root isolate.
[VERBOSE-2:shell.cc(588)] Could not launch engine with configuration.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67074432/cant-load-kernel-binary-invalid-sdk-hash-in-flutter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you delete the bin/cache folder, then run app

Comment: I already found it, and did what you described. Thanks though! :)

Comment: this does not worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Hi!

In my case, the error was caused by the forced shutdown of the IDE.

After manually selecting the libraries, I identified the one that was causing the problem, updated the project without it, and updated the project again with it.

With that the problem was solved.

Hope I have helped, if yes, please flag.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks a ton! this was in my case too my app was crashing in release mode on ios no logs at all. Running the app in xcode showed me few logs and I realized those logs were  from firebase crashlytics and analytics removing those plugins helped me fix the release crash.

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and run: **$ flutter channel beta**
"it will install beta version, once installation is done, try it!"

"In case you willing to change the beta version to stable version you can use the following:"

*$ flutter channel stable*